# Get parameter values from href in jquery

Tags: jquery, href

### **Script**

```
 <a href="#?cat=MT&typ=1" data-reveal-id="reveal_popup" onclick="pop();" data-closeonbackgroundclick="false" data-dismissmodalclass="close-reveal-modal">due today</a>
 <a href="#?cat=MT&typ=2" data-reveal-id="reveal_popup" onclick="pop();" data-closeonbackgroundclick="false" data-dismissmodalclass="close-reveal-modal">due in 2 days</a>

 <div id="reveal_popup" class="reveal-modal">
 <div id="popup"></div>
 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
 </div>

function pop() {

 var cat=**value of cat parameter in href**
 var type=**value of typ parameter in href**

 $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:site_url()+'/event/deleteEventSingle',
       data:{'cat':cat,'type':typ},
        async:false,
         success:function(result){}
        });
}
```

In this when the user clicks a href same popup appears with different data. there are more than 10 hrefs actually and i am trying to show a calender with user inputted data in the popup. This depends on two parameters **cat and typ** as shown in href.

### Requirement

Every href has its own cat and typ values. When a href is clicked I want the cat and typ values of the clicked href to be get using jquery so that i can pass these variables in ajax.

```
var cat=**value of cat parameter in href**
var type=**value of typ parameter in href**
```

### Tried

[How to get the parameters of an href attribute of a link from the click event object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343436/how-to-get-the-parameters-of-an-href-attribute-of-a-link-from-the-click-event-ob)

Comment: i suggest you use data-* attributes. like this 
` <a href="#" data-reveal-id="reveal_popup" onclick="pop();" data-closeonbackgroundclick="false" data-dismissmodalclass="close-reveal-modal" data-category="MT" data-cat-type="1">due today</a> `.

Comment: @Ravi: how can I get the values using this

Comment: you can use jquery data() method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do as soeme thing as below

```
$('a').bind('click',function(){
    var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
    var cat = getURLParameter(url, 'cat');
    var typ = getURLParameter(url, 'typ');
    //calling the ajax function
    pop(cat, typ)
});


function getURLParameter(url, name) {
    return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1];
}

function pop(cat, typ) {

    $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:site_url()+'/event/deleteEventSingle',
       data:{'cat':cat,'type':typ},
        async:false,
         success:function(result){}
    });
}
```

Check out the the example at Live fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/aY9vy/

Comment: did you check the fiddle when you click on the link it returns the correct value..

Comment: Can you Please have the same without ajax I asked the same in Below Link Please help me out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663358/how-to-remove-parameter-on-click-event-using-jquery-and-change-the-value-of-exis

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
function getUrlParams(url) {
    var params = {};
    url.substring(1).replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
            function (str, key, value) {
                 params[key] = value;
            });
    return params;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
function pop(e) {
     var url = $(e.target).attr("href");
     var params = getUrlParams(url); 

     var cat= params["cat"];
     var type= params["typ"];

     alert(cat);
     alert(type);    
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/umezas/6/edit)

Comment: i am getting value as undefined when i alert cat

Comment: Is the substring call needed? Seems to me its just bypassing the # portion of the URL in your demo.