# How to extract a attribute in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to extract a particular attribute from a tag.

I am getting

```
 var item=<a href="/tasks/new?count=2&amp;task_id=157" class="right">tttttttttttt_wo /   nnnnnnnnnn_wo</a>
```

From this i want to extract only task_id. How to do that?

Comment: task_id is not an attribute

Comment: @RakeshShetty sorry. How to take that task_id?

Comment: this post here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780717/get-parameter-values-from-href-in-jquery

Comment: is your var item a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that in 2 stages :

1. get attribute using `jquery.attr`
2. match that task_id regex using jquery match function

Code:

```
var strings =  $('a.right').attr("href").match(/task_id=[0-9]+/);    
alert(strings[0]);
```

jsfiddle for your [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/x05hfd6s/).

Answer (score 2):

You want to say like this ? - **[Fiddle Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/6bp5apns/)** OR **[Fiddle Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/s6oLsv3p/1/)**

**Fiddle Demo 1 Code :**

HTML :

```
<a href="/tasks/new?count=2&amp;task_id=157" task_id = "157" class="right">tttttttttttt_wo /   nnnnnnnnnn_wo</a>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.right').click(function(){

           var task_id = $(this).attr('task_id');
           alert(task_id);


    });

});
```

**Fiddle Demo 2 Code :**

HTML :

```
<a href="/tasks/new?count=2&amp;task_id=157" class="right">tttttttttttt_wo /   nnnnnnnnnn_wo</a>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.right').click(function(){

          alert($('a').attr('href').split("&").pop());    

    });

});
```

Comment: @poojaagarwal use as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML:
<a href="/tasks/new?count=2&task_id=157" class="right">tttttttttttt_wo /   nnnnnnnnnn_wo</a>

Jquery:
alert($('a').attr('href').split("&").pop());
```

Comment: So the OP should make their HTML invalid to allow this??! The answer andrew linked to is much better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, task_id is not an attribute, but href is. 
so you can get the value of href by

```
$('a.right').attr("href")
```