# Using dynamic links to trigger ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a couple of links that I want to trigger operations through ajax from, but I dont know how to continue on this matter. I've kind of solved it for static links but my links are dynamic and there will be different amount of links at different stages.

I have a index.php that looks like this:

```
<script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link1").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#result').empty().text('Executing command...'); 
     $('#result').load('ajax.php?op=edit&id=4', function(){         
        $('#result').before("The server answered:");
        $('#result').after("The operation was a success<br>");
    }); // end load
  }); //end click
}); //end ready()
</script>

<div id='result'></div>
<a id='link1' href='#'>Link 1</a><br>
<a id='link2' href='#'>Link 2</a><br>
<a id='link3' href='#'>Link 3</a><br>
<a id='link4' href='#'>Link 4</a><br>
<a id='link5' href='#'>Link 5</a><br>
<a id='link6' href='#'>Link 6</a><br>
```

And the "ajax" file looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['op']) && isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $op = $_GET['op'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    switch($op) {
        case "edit":
            // do operations here
            echo $id;
            break;
        case "doSomethingElse":
            // do other operations here
            echo $id;
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

So what I struggle with now is: How do I solve this so I don't have to define each link within the jquery ready() function?

Edit: 
Basicly I need to trigger an operation in the ajax.php file depending on what link I click.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a little confusing, are you just asking how to concatenate the ID into the URL, or how to make the event handlers work with dynamic elements *(event delegation)*  ?

Comment: You need to take a step back from this first and take note of what the common logic is between the button click actions is and then write the code to repeat that action. You've not really given enough information for someone to help you - we need to see a couple of example of the requests you're sending to see what's the same/different between them

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I could add one question in the end and ask both. I'll go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parameter values from href in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780717/get-parameter-values-from-href-in-jquery)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm new to this ajax technology. I don't understand what you're asking for. I was under the impression that "$('#result').load" was the ajax call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this selector;

```
$('[id^="link"]')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^="link"]').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#result').empty().text('Executing command...'); 
     $('#result').load('ajax.php?op=edit&id=4', function(){         
        $('#result').before("The server answered:");
        $('#result').after("The operation was a success<br>");
    }); // end load
  }); //end click
}); //end ready()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
<a id='link1' href='#'>Link 1</a><br>
<a id='link2' href='#'>Link 2</a><br>
<a id='link3' href='#'>Link 3</a><br>
<a id='link4' href='#'>Link 4</a><br>
<a id='link5' href='#'>Link 5</a><br>
<a id='link6' href='#'>Link 6</a><br>
```

Comment: Excellent answer my friend!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, You to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store arbitrary information with the element which can be used later.

```
<a class='link' href='#' data-key="1">Link 1</a>
```

Then using your existing click handler, You can use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to access the data. Using jQuery the same result can be achieved using [`.data('key')`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Use common class to bind the event handler
  $(".link").click(function(e) {
    var id = this.dataset.key;
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#result').empty().text('Executing command...'); 
    $('#result').load('ajax.php?op=edit&id='+id, function(){         
        $('#result').before("The server answered:");
        $('#result').after("The operation was a success<br>");
    }); // end load

  }); //end click
}); //end ready()
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add class to each link

2) Take click event for that class

```js
$(".lnk").click(function(e) { // take click event for link
     e.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/); // get integer value from id so you will get id
     alert(id)
     $('#result').empty().text('Executing command...'); 
     $('#result').load('ajax.php?op=edit&id='+id, function(){         
        $('#result').before("The server answered:");
        $('#result').after("The operation was a success<br>");
    }); // end load
  }); //end click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
<a id='link1' href='#' class="lnk">Link 1</a><br>
<a id='link2' href='#' class="lnk">Link 2</a><br>
<a id='link3' href='#' class="lnk">Link 3</a><br>
<a id='link4' href='#' class="lnk">Link 4</a><br>
<a id='link5' href='#' class="lnk">Link 5</a><br>
<a id='link6' href='#' class="lnk">Link 6</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) attribute selector:

```
$('[id^="link"]')
```

```js
$('[id^="link"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.clear();  
  console.log('$(this).html():', $(this).html());
  // Your code...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='result'></div>
<a id='link1' href='#'>Link 1</a><br>
<a id='link2' href='#'>Link 2</a><br>
<a id='link3' href='#'>Link 3</a><br>
<a id='link4' href='#'>Link 4</a><br>
<a id='link5' href='#'>Link 5</a><br>
<a id='link6' href='#'>Link 6</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map events to dynamically loaded elements with `on` :

```
$("#staticParentContainer").on("click", "#dynamicElement", function() {
    // up to you
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/on/