# Trying to pass a value and recieve it on server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to pass a value from client side and recieve it on server side on click of hyperlink.but it should not be called everytime on page load ,currently i am trying like this but it is reloaded every time when page load.so i want it to be called one time.
on click event of hyperlink TDC_No passing value to tdc.aspx

```
 $.each(customers, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
 $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").text($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href", "TDC.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
});
```

calling at page load side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
    {
     TW12HVGI();
    }
```

}

```
Any idea would be appreciated.
```

Comment: you can use event onclick="return SingleTimeClick();" to control redirection by returing true or false value from Javav Script function.

Comment: if you are calling on `page_load` then it will be called everytime whenever the page is refreshed or loaded. You need to move your code from here.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're aiming for here. Do you mean that you pass the value - and the page loads but then subsequent actions on that page cause the TW12 function to execute again?

If so you are probably looking for a check on IsPostBack:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack){
        //if its not a post back - check for query string and run the TW12 function
        if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
            TW12HVGI();
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i want this function to be called once .only on click of hyperlink      
 $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").text($(this).find("TDC_NO").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href", "TDC.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text());

Comment: It seems like you are trying to click a link on a grid row...but what are you trying to do with that? Are you trying to open a page with it's details?

Comment: don't need ajax simply can i pass a query string value on click of hyperlink to a method in server that method should not be in page load

Comment: You can set a hidden field flag from code behind from first time call and read that flag from javascript to decide that function should call or not.

Comment: What is your server side code using? How are you rendering the rows? Is it possible to use a asp:Button (with CommandArguments) or asp:Hyperlink control? You can generally have these post back to the server for you and call their own Click handlers.

Comment: @ScottMoniz i am using c# no i am using jquery hyperlink function and i want to pass that parameter to server side

Comment: To pass parameters from Client side to Server side you have a few options:
1 - Open a page and pass the parameter in the query string
2 - AJAX callback
3 - Some sort of ASP control Post back
4 - A form submit

Comment: either you can use onclick method with href tag and control page redirection by returning true or false on second time like below <a href="https://example.com/no-js-login" onclick="return SingleTimeClick();">Log in</a>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive it on server side you will need to post back it using AJAX. On click of hyperlink send an ajax call and data to be saved along with it and then you will receive what ever you sent in action specified in ajax call.

Comment: can you show me the syntax how to implement ajax on click of dynamic hyperlink. $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").text($(this).find("TDC_NO").text()); $("td", row).eq(0).find("a").attr("href", "TDC.aspx?Id=" + $(this).find("TDC_NO").text());

Comment: try this link if you can find what you need, otherwise you will need to study AJAX a little and you will be good to go.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609319/using-dynamic-links-to-trigger-ajax