# Grab the end text of url from href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link that opens a page with information. I need to grab that information and display it on a section of another page. I have a link that uses a token to grab the appropriate link because each page is different. An example link looks like the following:

```
<a id="ItemDetail_SpecPageLink" style="display: none;" class="ItemDetailLocAvail" href="/customer/wetosu/specpages/FactoryStock.aspx?item=65048"></a>
```

The only part of the link to change is everything after `item=`. I started to code what I know but I don't know how to write in code "grab everything after `item=`" and set it as var. I couldn't find a question like mine on here as everyone's trying to find the same specific text of a link and with mine, I need to grab whatever is after `item=`.

I'm using this coding to grab the information, and I know my var `factoryLink` grabs the whole link but that is the part I'm stuck on and I didn't want to leave it as nothing:

```
//GET FACTORY AVAILABILITY
var factoryLink = $('#ItemDetail_SpecPageLink').attr('href');

$.ajax({
    url: ('/customer/wetosu/specpages/FactoryStock.aspx?item=' + factoryLink),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#FactoryAvailability').html(data);
    }
});
```

Any help is apprecited!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parameter values from href in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780717/get-parameter-values-from-href-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
item=(.+)$
```

Regex breakdown:

- `item=` the first part of what you want to match
- `(` the start of the [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `.+` says match anything after an unlimited times
- `)` the end of the capturing group
- `$` the end of the string

[The result of `String.prototype.match` is an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value), the first argument is the whole match and the second argument in the first capturing group.

Hope this helps.

```js
var factoryLink = $('#ItemDetail_SpecPageLink').attr('href');

var yourId = factoryLink.match(/item=(.+)$/)[1];

console.log({yourId});

// do what you want with it
// $.ajax({
//   url: ('/customer/wetosu/specpages/FactoryStock.aspx?item=' + yourId),
//   type: 'GET',
//   success: function(data) {
//     $('#FactoryAvailability').html(data);
//   }
// });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a id="ItemDetail_SpecPageLink" class="ItemDetailLocAvail" href="/customer/wetosu/specpages/FactoryStock.aspx?item=65048">Some link</a>
```

[Read more about javascript's regex on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)