# How to remove parameter on Click event using jQuery and Change the value of existing parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="paginationSize">
     <li>SHOW:</li>
     <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="20" class=""><a href="#">20</a>
     </li>
     <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="40" class=""><a href="#">40</a>
     </li>
     <li id="paginationClass" data-paginationValue="60" class=""><a href="#">60</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

<ul class="paginationNumber">
    <?php for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>
    <li data-paginationNumber="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href=""><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**jQuery Related to the PHP CODE**

```
$(".paginationSize li").click(function(){
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        paginationSize =  $(this).attr("data-paginationValue");
        setGetParameter('pageSize',paginationSize);
    });
```

**setGetParameter Function** - Used to append parameter on click event

```
function setGetParameter(paramName, paramValue)
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var hash = location.hash;
    url = url.replace(hash, '');
    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0)
    {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    }
    else
    {
    if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url + hash;
}
```

I want to add parameter on both ul's Click event 
But when I click on paginationSize ul it should remove the paginationNumber parameter from URL and update the value whichever click on paginationSize URL

**Expected Output:**:

```
Previous Link Before Click:localhost/projectname?paginationSize=20&pageNum=5
When I click on 40 it should have following output:localhost/projectname?paginationSize=40
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you've described what it should do. What does the code currently do? What is the issue with it?

Comment: As per curren code i am unable o remove paramtewr of pageNum on paginationSize Click

Comment: You've already told me what is _doesn't_ do. I was asking what it _does_ do. As a basic question...simply tell me, what URL does it output now? e.g. It's hard to see how it's ever going to output "paginationSize" when you tell it to look for a parameter called "pageSize". I would guess the output currently will be something like `localhost/projectname?pageSize=20` if you click on the first `li`.

Comment: Yes Currently it is exactly the same you wrote

Comment: ok so then `setGetParameter('pageSize',paginationSize);` should probably be `setGetParameter('paginationSize',paginationSize);`. I would guess that's sufficient to fix it.

Comment: Actually we can have any paramter for get

Comment: When i debug it it is not allowing me to call 2 times setgetparamter
as of it is redirecting need solution which can allow me to call function 2 times

Comment: The parameter name that is output in your URL is dependent on what you set as "paramName". Therefore you need to set it as "paginationSize" if you want "paginationSize" in the output URL.

Comment: if you don't want it to redirect, then remove the line of code which causes the redirect.

Comment: Srry My Mistake 
Need localhost/projectname?pageSize=20&pageNum=5
On click of paginationSize remove pageNum param

Comment: It won't allow me to remove pageNum while click on paginationSize

Comment: well there's nothing in the code which is designed to do that. Were you expecting it to work, or are you asking how removing the parameter should be done? Will it always be "pageNum" that you want to remove, or could it be any parameter name?

Comment: Or do you in fact want to remove _all_ potential other parameters except for the one given as the "paramName" variable?

Comment: Yes exactly .What Happens is it won't allow me to call server parameter function two times on a single click due to window .location.href

Comment: yes I already told you to remove that if you don't want it.

Comment: I wan't to remove it at runtime

Comment: I don't understand...you want to remove the 'window.location.href'command at runtime? You mean you want to decide whether to execute it or not based on some condition. You can't remove a piece of code at runtime, you can only use logic to decide whether it gets executed, like an if statement